# Angular post request parameters not being passed correctly

Tags: angular

I am trying to do a post request in Angular. I need to pass a model as a parameter however I am getting an error.

Here is my code

Model

```
  protected initModel() {
    this.model = {
      basics: null,
      retirements: null,
      risk: null,
      users: null
    };
  }
```

Function to assign values to model

```
  saveTemp( args: { tabName: string, tabModel: any } ) {
    switch (args.tabName) {
      case 'basics': {
        this.model.basics = args.tabModel;
        // console.log(this.model.basics);
        break;
      }
      case 'retirement': {
        this.model.retirements = args.tabModel;
        break;
      }
      case 'risk': {
        this.model.risk = args.tabModel;
        break;
      }
      case 'users': {
        this.model.users = args.tabModel;
        break;
      }
      default: {
        break;
      }
    }
  }
```

Post request

```
const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
const headers = new HttpHeaders()
  .set('Authorization', `Bearer ${token}`)
  .set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
const options = { headers: headers };
this.http.post('https://localhost:44345/api/Corporates/Create', this.saveTemp( args: { basic, this.model.basics } ), options)
.subscribe(data => {
  console.log(data);
})
```

The error is me passing the saveTemp function with parameter is the post request "Expected 1 arguments, but got 2."

[image]

Comment: Could you post full error message?

Comment: This is from my text editor. The way I am passing the data to the post request is incorrect. `Module parse failed: Unexpected token (215:114)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|             .set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
|         var options = { headers: headers };
>         this.http.post('https://localhost:44345/api/Corporates/Create', this.saveTemp(args, { basic: basic, this: .model.basics }), options)
|             .subscribe(function (data) {
|             console.log(data);
`

Comment: Angular post method signature `post(url: string, body: any | null ...)` does not invoke the inline method `saveTemp`. Although the type is `any`, it expects any of the support JSON types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is invalid. `this.saveTemp` is not invoked correctly and it doesn't return any value.

```
this.http.post(URL, this.saveTemp( args: { basic, this.model.basics } ), options)
```

Try to invoke `saveTemp` before making the request and pass only model:

```
this.http.post(URL, this.model, options)
```

Comment: Thanks I see my mistake

Answer (score 1):

another approach for sending model

```
apiUrl:string="";
getLoggedInUser(model:any): Observable<any> {
  const headers = new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer token'
  })
  return this.http.post<any>(this.apiUrl,model,{headers:headers})
}
```